# C#: Is it possible to get the index of a DropDownItem in a menu item?

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu

Is it possible to get the index of an item in a dropdown menu?

Comment: Please elaborate, there is not enough information.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you're trying to do. Could you provide more details about your specific scenario?

Comment: What kind of dropdown menu? WPF/Forms, etc.?

Comment: I have a menu item called "Projects" and everytime i create a new project or open a project it is added to this menuitem as a Dropdown item. When i then click the dropdown item i want to pass along the index of the menu item.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
private void item_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ToolStripMenuItem item = sender as ToolStripMenuItem;
    if (item != null)
    {
        int index = (item.OwnerItem as ToolStripMenuItem).DropDownItems.IndexOf(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Petar - one of the menu items has items add'ed to the DropDownItems list. And i want to find the index of the dropdown item i click on.

Comment: @devnull - works perfectly! Thanks a bunch! I've accepted the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The above solution may throw a null when casting to ToolStripMenuItem and there's some fluff. This one is cleaner:

```
private void item_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ToolStripMenuItem item = sender as ToolStripMenuItem;
    if (item != null)
    {
        int index = ContextMenuStrip.Items.IndexOf(commentMenuItem);
    }
}
```